# Not able to combine two queries in one

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch all customer_details will all fields and total count of bill and sum of bill amount that is stored in `customer_details(id,name,address,...)` and `bill_details(bill_no,customer_id,price,...)` table.

Basic query to fetch both are first this:

```
select  cd.* from customer_details as cd
```

Then this:

```
select customer_id,count(*) as billCount,sum(total) price from bill_details group by customer_id;
```

I am not able to combine these two in one query to fetch all customer details with bill sum and count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `JOIN`:

```
SELECT cd.*,IFNULL(T.billCount,0) as billCount,IFNULL(T.price,0) as price
FROM customer_details as cd LEFT JOIN
(SELECT customer_id,count(*) as billCount,sum(total) price 
 FROM bill_details 
 GROUP BY customer_id) T ON cd.id=T.customer_id
```

Comment: Unknown column  T1.price is unknown,  Unknown column 'cd.customer_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: @xrcwrn: Oops!! Sorry, that was a typo. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried following goving correct result Can I use this

```
select  cd.*,IFNULL(count(*),0) as count,IFNULL(sum(bd.total),0) as total from customer_details as cd
left join bill_details as bd
on cd.id=bd.customer_id
group by cd.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cd.id,
       cd.nmae, 
       cd.address
       IFNULLCOUNT(bd.*),0) AS billcount, 
       IFNULL(SUM(bd.price * bd.quantity),0) as total /* I suppose you have a quantity field in bd */
FROM customer_details cd
LEFT JOIN bill_details bd
ON cd.id = bd.customer_id
GROUP BY cd.id, 
         cd.nmae, 
         cd.address
```